# android connect to remote machine over ssh

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

From android how can i connect to a server as in ubuntu and view the files on it over ssh and not through the command mode.

Also here i am not looking at an app to use but to get the libraries to do this

from command line i know i can use the app connectbot [Connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) but i want to login to the remote machine and view the files on a file browser on the device.Are there any links pertaining to this please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/jssh/ or http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: i tried jsch can u give me code examples any link would do.  Also i have tried this for JSCH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177225/android-ssh-to-remote-machine-vis-jsch